# Error calculation for experimental data

Tags: experimental-physics, statistics, error-analysis

I have the list of experimental values:
$$\{w_i \pm \Delta w_i\},$$
where $w_j$ is a mean value and $\Delta w_i$ is an error.

I want to calculate the second list $\{a_i \pm \Delta a_i\}$ according to the rule
$$a_i = \frac{w_i / A_i}{\sum_j w_j / A_j},$$
where $A_i$ is some constant for $i$.

How to define errors $\Delta a_i$? Is it the right way?

$$\Delta a_i = \frac{1}{A_i} \frac{\Delta w_i |\sum_j w_j/A_j| + |w_i|\sum_j \Delta w_j/A_j}{(\sum_j w_j/A_j)^2}$$

Comment: I don't have the energy to check your workings but the relevant maths is [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propagation_of_uncertainty). Alternatively you can find a list of free software [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_uncertainty_propagation_software) that computes such things for you.

Comment: It depends on what kind of uncertainties you are dealing with. Due you assume that it is [normal distributed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution), where the error is (a multiple of) the standard deviation, or do you assume 100% confidence intervals?

Comment: In your 1st equation , I think you have mistaken wi for wj.

Answer (score 1):

According to [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propagation_of_uncertainty) from foregoing comment $a_i$ measurments are inderect, so errors are

$$\Delta a_{i}=\sqrt{\sum_{k}\left(\frac{\partial a_{i}}{\partial w_{k}}\Delta w_{k}\right)^{2}}.$$

After calculations it yields
$$\Delta a_{i}= \frac{1}{\left(\sum_{j}\frac{w_{j}}{A_{j}}\right)^{2}A_{i}}\sqrt{\sum_{k}\left( \left[\delta_{ik}\sum_{j}\frac{w_{j}}{A_{j}}-\frac{w_{i}}{A_{k}} \right] \Delta w_{k} \right)^{2}}$$

Comment: What does inderect mean? Perhaps a typo for indirect, but surely the word you want there is independent?